# How to sort NSMutableArray of date objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I'm doing some small work on sorting the date strings in the NSMutableArray, i'm getting the array from the sqlite db. 
If you print the array it is showing like this

date strings are (
    "2011-05-01",
    "2011-02-01",
    "2012-01-08",
    "2012-05-08",
    "2010-01-09
)

I want to show the dates in ascending order. Please help me out guys..... I'm newbie to objc..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you should convert all date Strings (which is `NSString`) objects to `NSDate` objects and then sort these `dateObjects`.

I believe you have `dateArray` containing all those strings.

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" 
                                                           ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

*OR*

```
NSArray *reverseOrderUsingComparator = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
                                       ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                           return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                                       }];
```

Comment: The date format he showed in his question will sort correctly even as strings.

Comment: That's unnecessary, he can just arrange the strings as they are right now.

Comment: Nice thanks man.... I used ur second one, but it is showing the array objects in descending order...how can i do it for ascending

Answer (score 5):

If your dates are really strings in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`, as in your question, then this will sort them in ascending order:

```
[arrayOfDates sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

That will also work if your dates are actually `NSDate` objects.

If you want to create a sorted copy of the array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfDates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting should be done, imo, by the database, in general. sqlite3 does support [order by](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).