# Sorting Array Using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of class A objects, let it be detailsArray.

Class A has date, name as properties.

Can any one suggest a good method to sort this array based on date?

How can I use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort this array? I know sorting array of dictionary using `NSSortDescriptor`...

Any help is greatly appreciated.....

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667288/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-of-date-objects

Comment: I didn't see it, Sorry....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [detailsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Should be: sortedArrayUsingDescriptors

Answer (score 5):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];

NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

or you can use a block also

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(A *a, A *b) {
    NSDate *first = a.date;
    NSDate *second = b.date;
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give key forward by its class name, like

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ClassA.date" ascending:YES];
```

and **do** google your queries before ask any question, see the google crawler [**result.**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sort+NSArray+contains+custom+class+objects&aq=f&oq=sort+NSArray+contains+custom+class+objects&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.9997&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)