# Challenging query in COREDATA

Tags: ios, core-data

In my Core Data application I have only one table like this:

[image]

What I want is a query which returns all rows group by subject in the ascending order of date,
ie [image: Required output]

I am not familiar with Core Data predicates. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667288/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-of-date-objects

Comment: Please refere below link,it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942912/how-to-group-by-day-in-nsdate-with-nspredicate-needed-to-create-multiple-uitab

Comment: `SELECT * FROM YOUR TABLE_NAME GROUP BY Subject WHERE Date ASC;`

Comment: @Jeff why minus vote? i tried to help you by giving some example.

Comment: @Hemang When I used your code app crashes with following exception *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SELECT * FROM Message GROUP BY Subject WHERE Date ASC"'

Answer (score 2):

you can write the code like this :-

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Subject == 'Leave'"];
```

you will get the list of Subjects with title Leave.Now you can Modify the code as per your requirement.

This will help you to get them in ascending order:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

For   references:-https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: please comment what is wrong here for minus vote?

Comment: Atleast read the question before giving answer

Comment: @Jeff  i read the question..if so,please don't tag with iOS,tag it with mac OS.