# Sort Time Range in Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array like

```
<__NSArrayI 0xa8434a0>(
{
    From = "10:01AM";
    Title = Discuss;
    To = "12:00AM";
},
{
    From = "12:01AM";
    Title = Discuss;
    To = "02:00AM";
},
{
    From = "5:01AM";
    Title = Available;
    To = "7:00AM";
},
{
    From = "2:01AM";
    Title = Discuss;
    To = "5:00AM";
},
{
    From = "7:01AM";
    Title = Available;
    To = "12:00pM";
}
)
```

How can I sort this array as per time range using From & to key?

I tried as follow:

But Not well

```
sortedDatesArray = [[unsortedDatesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *d1 = [NSDate dateWithString: s1];
    NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithString: s2];
    return [d1 compare: d2];
}];
```

**Help me to solve this.**

Comment: That array won't even compile.

Comment: Now it makes much more sense. So it's an array of dictionaries with three keys. By which key do you want to sort it?

Comment: @Desdenova, Thanks for reply... It likes 24 hours a day. If need to sort using "From & To" (i.e. Time Range)

Comment: I'm not sure if the range is sortable. What happens if a title starts the earliest but takes the most time and so on?

Comment: @Desdenova, Sorry I am not getting you. please explain in detail.

Comment: Try to understand what's going on here, it's a bit similar with your situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667288/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-of-date-objects

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *toSortArray = nil; /*The array you want to sort*/
NSArray *sortedArray = nil;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptorTo = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"To" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *firstDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *secondDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [firstDate compare:secondDate];
}];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptorFrom = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"From" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *firstDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *secondDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [firstDate compare:secondDate];
}];

sortedArray = [toSortArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptorFrom, descriptorTo]];
```

I hope this answer your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
    [times sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* obj1, NSString *obj2) {
        NSDate *firstDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
        NSDate *secondDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];
        return [firstDate compare:secondDate];
    }];
```

Comment: Although this is not the answer to the question, the format you want to use is `@"hh:mma"`

Answer (score -1):

I tried with your code, Try the following code. I changed fields from your array. Or you can change the date format.

```
NSMutableArray *timesArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"05:00 AM",@"08:00 AM",@"10:00 AM",@"05:01 AM" ,@"7:59 AM",@"12:00 AM", nil];
NSDateFormatter *formt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formt setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[timesArr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* ob1, NSString *ob2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [formt dateFromString:ob1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formt dateFromString:ob2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
NSLog(@"timesArr: %@",timesArr);
```