# Sort descriptor not working on nsdate objects in NSArray.

Tags: objective-c

An array contains NSDate objects, how to sort these using sort descriptor ? I am trying the code below:

```
NSSortDescriptor * dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES];

NSArray * sortedArray = [allDates addObjectsFromArray:[allDates sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateSortDescriptor]]];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort NSMutableArray of date objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667288/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-of-date-objects)

Answer (score 2):

NSDate conforms to the `compare:` method and ascending is the default order

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [allDates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Avt, answered this question I don't know why he removed it.

```
NSSortDescriptor * dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timeIntervalSince1970" ascending:YES];

NSArray * sortedArray = [allDates addObjectsFromArray:[allDates sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateSortDescriptor]]];
```

Comment: @Avt <http://stackoverflow.com/users/3140927/avt?tab=profile> please post your answer again its working fine :)

Comment: In any event, @vadian has a slicker way of doing it.  No custom sortDescriptor necessary.